# Continue foreach loop from middle

Tags: php, foreach

I have this for each loop:

```
  foreach($downloads as $dl) { 
echo seosvelniau2($dl['title']);
}
```

By default it gives me 50 results, is there any way to split this foreach loop into two (1-25) and (26-50), so I can put both into two separate table columns?
I know, that i can make loop to show only first 25 results like this:

```
 $i=0;
foreach($downloads as $dl) { 
 $i++;
    echo seosvelniau2($dl['title']);
if ($i == 25)
break;
    }
```

but how to do second loop to show (26-50) results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can divide the array `$downloads` even before the loop.(using `array_chunk`)

```
$Chunks = array_chunk($downloads , 25);
foreach($Chunks[0] as $dl)
{
       //Group 1
}

foreach($Chunks[1] as $dl)
{
    ///Group2
}
```

EDIT: Here's a general example: (In case you have more than 50 elements)

```
$Chunks = array_chunk($downloads , 25);
foreach($Chunks as $oneChunk)
{
  //New group of 25 elements.
  foreach($oneChunk as $dl)
  {

  }   

}
```

Comment: I used it only once and was surprised to find it, never forgot it since than.

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm! As I'm kinda new to php, the array_chunk is totally new to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Two different approaches:

---

Use each to iterate over the array.

```
$i = 0;
while(list($id, $item) = each($array)) {
    echo $item;
    if (++$i == 25) { break; }
}

while(list($id, $item) = each($array)) {
    echo $item;
}
```

---

If you don't need that array after the loop is complete, you can simply shift the items:

```
$i = 0;
while (++$i < 25 && count($array)) {
    $item = array_shift($array);
    echo $item;
}

foreach ($array as $item) {
    echo $item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could switch the columns in between:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($downloads as $dl) {
    if (++$i === 25) echo '</tr><tr>';
    echo seosvelniau2($dl['title']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
$i=0;
foreach($downloads as $dl) { 
 $i++;
 if ($i <= 25){
  //first 25
 }else{
  //rest
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the process if drawing an HTML table, and you need to switch `td`, just do something like this:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $downloads ); $i++ )
{
    echo seosvelniau2( $downloads[ i ][ 'title' ] );
    if ( $i % 25 == 0 )
    {
        echo( '</td><td>' );
    }
}
```

This will create a new columns every 25 values.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you just use a normal `for` loop instead of `foreach`?  Then you can determine the start and end points manually, [like so.](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp)

Then you should have something more or less like this:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=25; $i++)
{
    echo "The number is " . $i . "<br />";
}

for ($i=26; $i<=50; $i++)
{
    echo "The number is " . $i . "<br />";
}
```